# WordPress Bullets - Text Wrapping Under Bullets

Tags: css, wordpress

Using WordPress and I want to avoid having the second line text of my bullet points wrap down under the bullets. I'd like clean bullets to one side and text to the other. This is the CSS I am using. Any thoughts?

```
.entry-content ul li { list-style-type: none; font-size: 100%; list-style-position: outside;} .entry-content ul li:before { content: "✓"; padding-right: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; color: #718336; }
```

Answer (score 1):

try the outside position on the UL instead of the li:

```
.entry-content ul {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp

for the :before tag, you'll want to position that absolutely and move it to where the circle was (or try negative margin-left) should get you what you are looking for*

Comment: Do you mean add this in addition to what I had, but with the list-style-position removed from what I had? If so, I did that and it still doesn't stop the wrapping. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Do you have a url so I can check it out?

Comment: See the before: comment, I think that will work for what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks - still a little stumped :)

Comment: Perhaps a better reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position